# Table sorting fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have data in a table coming from multiple json api links.

my code currently is

```
<script src="js/1.js"></script>
<script src="js/2.js"></script>
```

Above this is a table code. Allowing the table to be sorted. It only has  `<th>` and  `<thead>` tags.

The issue as it stands looks like this:

[image: example]

I'm wanting ideally the price field to be sorted. below is the inside of the JS files

1.js

```
$.ajax({
    type        : 'GET',
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType    : 'json',
    url         : 'api link here',
    success     : function (json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);            
        for(var i=0; i<json.results.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results[i].section;
            var no = json.results[i].avalible;
            var price = json.results[i].price;
            var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Compare</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
            $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
                 location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
    },
    error        : function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

and here is the 2nd js file

```
$.ajax({
    type        : 'GET',
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType    : 'json',
    url         : '2nd api',
    success     : function (json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var i=0; i<json.results.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results[i].section;
            var no = json.results[i].avalible;
            var price = json.results[i].amount;
            var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
            $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
    },
    error        : function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Now here is what i believe is the code to sort the js files in the table, Issue is I have no idea where to put it.

```
var sortTable = function(){ 
    $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function(a,b){
    //substring was added to omit currency sign, you can remove it if data-price attribute does not contain it.
        return parseFloat($(a).data('price').substring(1))- parseFloat($(b).data('price').substring(1));
    })
    .appendTo('#tableid tbody');
};
```

And

```
for(var i=0; i<json.results.length; i++) {
    ....
}
sortTable();
```

I would use a tablesorter jquery plugin but i would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're pulling data from two ajax requests, perhaps it will be better to store both results in one global array that you can sort and loop through to build your table in price order.

```
var resultsArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
    resultsArray.push(json.results[i]);
}
resultsArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
    //print your table here
    var price = resultsArray[i].price;
    //etc...
}
```

I fully demonstrated this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/L41fy7rb/1/)

Comment: Hey there, Where would i then put the urls? Sorry for being a noob question :)

Comment: Hi there, i also just tried adding the table in and it didnt sort the price, See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vn8zapzu/3/

Comment: @SamRoberts Is it a requirement that you use 2 different script files in this way? What if you combined them into one file - would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible for you to take both of the json reponses, sort them in order by price, and then add them to the dom? This way you don't have to access the dom so much just to sort your data?

This would go something like this, if you're using jQuery. Basically once both of your ajax requests resolve you can do whatever with the data you have. Fromt here you can merge them, sort them, and then run your piece to populate the table.

```
var urlDatas = [];
$.when(
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function(data) {
        urlDatas.push(data);
    }),
    $.getJSON(someOtherUrl, function(data) {
        urlDatas.push(data);
    })
).then(function() {
    //not completely sure if extend returns a value or just mutates, target.
    finalData = $.extend(true, {}, urlDatas[0], urlDatas[1]);

    //run a sort on that data
    sortData(finalData);

    //add it to your dom
    insertData(finalData);
});
```

Comment: i have no idea o.o Super new to all of this, Not sure how or where to add this with whats working now:)

Comment: what does the json data look like?

Comment: the json comes from a url. {
            "price": "£107 .00"
        },
        {
            "section": "Standing"
        },
        {
            "avalible": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ]
        },